How to aggregate the datediff values of multiple instance
The data I need requires to add the total time for each specific change,
How can I datediff the timestamp between value 1 = Review value 2 = Review in Progress when the value1= Review in Progress and do this everytime that happen then add all the time together in mysql.

I tried the following line but this datediff the first time and the last time the values where matched.
select datediff(day, cast(min(created) as DATETIME), cast(max(created)as DATETIME)) 
from table 
where id=555755 and identifier='64230be02cee496759ecf80d'

I was expecting to have a total of the hours spent when the changes had been made


We don't post images of sample data here. You will be more likely to get an answer if you edit the question to include the sample data and results as formatted text.

ok I tried doing that but it formatted as images instead, ill sort it out thank you

You can take time from previous row datediff(day, time, lag(time,1,created)over(partition by id order by time) )

Since you've already got an identifier and an ID, maybe try creating an extra column that increments every time you hit a 'review in progress' value1.
Something like:
sum(case when value1 = 'review in progress' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id order by time asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) as review_cntr
put that in a volatile table, then you can do
select
id, review_cntr, min(time) as min_time, max(time) as max_time
...
and then you have that to mess around with
You could make that a volatile table also and join it to itself on a.id = b.id and a.review_cntr + 1 = b.review_cntr and then use the appropriate min or max with a date diff
